# Why is my ASP.net MVC site not serving pages on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, windows-server-2008

Why is my ASP.net MVC site not serving pages on Windows Server 2008? The website is running under an application pool that has the .net framework 4.0 in integrated mode. It serves .htm files with no problem. However, when I try to view any of the MVC pages I get a page saying "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage." How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. This was a pain to track down. The server hosts 2 websites. The HTTPS bindings were not associated with the IP address for the website. Instead, the IP binding was set to "All unassigned".

The solution was to associate the HTTPS binding with the website's IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Server 2008 with IIS 7 you need to look at the website in question and go to the HandlerMappings settings. You need to make sure that the .Net mappings are set to enabled.

Comment: I don't see any .net mappings under handlerMappings. Please clarify.

Comment: @Tarzan - You should see mappings for .aspx, .ascx, .ashx, .asmx, and many more in there. If you don't, then .Net Framework 4.0 is not installed on your server.

Comment: The .net framework 4.0 is installed. Are you looking at the web.config or something else?

Comment: @Tarzan - No, it is in the IIS Manager itself (which is why I voted to move this question to ServerFault). When looking at the setup for the website, there is an icon for HandlerMappings. It is in this area that all file names that are to be processed by an external library (asp.net uses aspnet_isapi.dll) where those file extensions are mapped to their appropriate libraries and also where they are enabled or disabled.

Comment: Joel, I am giving you a +1 for making good recommendations. Thanks for your suggestions.